# Why are my automation scripts failing on Production Sites?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, cypress

I'm trying to run some selenium and cypress scripts on production sites such as [Amazon India](https://www.amazon.in) and [MakeMyTrip](https://www.makemeytrip.com).

However, my scripts keep failing continuously.

Cypress refuses to even open the page and times out.

My Selenium script opens the page but refuses to locate certain elements even though they are plainly visible and I can see them using the element search via Xpath or CSS.

For example, I'm running an automation script with the steps below:

1. Open the Amazon India Site.
2. Enter the text "Samsung Galaxy M34 mobile" in the search box.
3. Click on the first link displayed in the search results page.

Now, I am using this X-path selector to define the search options link text:

```
//div[@data-cy='title-recipe']
```

My aim being to store it in a List and derive the first element from the list and click it.

However, during script execution I see the error "index 0 out of bounds for length 0" which indicates that the element hasn't been detected at all. Similar errors are observed for other CSS and X-path selectors.

I understand that being live production sites, these pages might be having some protective measures installed to prevent anyone from accessing the site and doing mischief. Is there any override?

I've tried using some dummy sites for practicing automation testing, but they're not reliable and not production like. The DB keeps reseeding every 5-10 minutes, deleting all the test data I've created and sometimes, the page throws an error.

As an alternative, are there any production like 'reliable' websites to practice Automation?

Answer (score 0):

> Cypress refuses to even open the page and times out.

Without knowing what website you are targeting and the code you are using, we can't help here.

> However, during script execution I see the error "index 0 out of
> bounds for length 0" which indicates that the element hasn't been
> detected at all

Apparently there is no text *title-recipe* on the DOM.

[image]

You probably should search by the search bar ID.

[image]

> are there any production like 'reliable' websites to practice
> Automation?

SauceLab's [The Internet](https://github.com/saucelabs/the-internet) aims at this. You can find an instance [here](https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/).
Alternatively, you can build open source websites for practice. [Here is a list of examples in Cypress](https://chat.openai.com/share/873f61c8-21cc-4c5e-bed6-ddf999956074).